# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments with Data(contentOf:)

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode

I am trying to encode and decode `json` data it swift 4.2 but am running to this error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments` am not sure what am doing wrong, have tried what have find in stack regarding the error with no success. 
Here is my code
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

```
import Foundation

struct Section : Codable {
    var title : String
    var caption : String
    var body : String
    var imageName : String
    var publishDate : Date

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title, caption, body
        case imageName = "image"
        case publishDate = "publish_date"
    }
}

class ContentAPI {

    static var shared : ContentAPI = ContentAPI()


    lazy var sections : Array<Section> = {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        return try! decoder.decode(Array<Section>.self, from: data)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code is correct. Is there a `Data` extension with additional initializers?

As the file is in the bundle and cannot be changed at runtime you can force unwrap all values. The code **must not** crash.

```
lazy var sections : Array<Section> = {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    return try! decoder.decode(Array<Section>.self, from: data)
}()
```

Comment: am still getting the same error on this line `let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)` it highlights the `url` with the errorI have updated my entire code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. `Data(contentsOf:` is correct code. There must be something in your project which hides this build-in initializer.

Comment: Thanks, what can I do to figure out the problem have been stuck with this error for some time now. lemme clean the project and XCode cache and see if it will fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you forget the trailing `}()` otherwise the code should run safely and won't cause a crash if the file exists or not

```
lazy var sections : Array<Section> = {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "json") else { return [] }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return [] }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        let sections = try decoder.decode(Array<Section>.self, from: data)
        return sections
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return []
}()
```

Comment: The missing parentheses cause the error message *Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'Array<Section>'* but not the mentioned error in the question.

Comment: @vadian the compiler always glitches in this  case the code snippet should work and so on will the other parts